# 3D model format for OpenGL ES Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, 3d-model

when I was working with XNA model format was obvious .X or .FBX, they had bones so I was able to do animation and collision detection, they probably had everything I needed. But now I started to work with Android and OpenGL ES and I can't seem to find anything about preferred model formats, I keep seeing .OBJ but they don't support bones, I also read something about collada and md5 formats but heard there are some problems with loading them? Also suggestions with min3d but I don't like the idea using third party stuff.

Could someone please explain a bit the situation with models and OpenGL ES, why there are no preferred obvious choices(at least from my point of view), and what format or solution should I go with?

Also this is my first question, please write suggestions if I didn't explain myself right or made any other question errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL ES is much much more low level than XNA, it does not provide anything related to 3d models 'management', and thus, has no preferred model/file format or bone management.

Basically, if you don't like the idea of using 'third party stuff', then you'll have to pick whatever 3d model format you see fit, and do it all on your own.

OpenGL ES is basically a specification, nothing more, the 'SDK' provided by [Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/) contains only 1 library. Generally, development resources are provided by the various hardware vendors, in the form of code samples.

Comment: Now I get it. OpenGL is not aware about models, everybody has to marry them themselves or use an importer that someone else wrote. Thanks rotoglup.